# how remove <td>..</td> when echo-ing value inside text input?

Tags: php, input

I encountered a very strange issue, that I never seen before. I have a loop and I echo the loop's output without any problems using

or other similar tags:

```
<p></php echo $values[1];?></p>
```

it works like a charm, but when I try to echo the same value inside a text input strange things start to happen. The output inside an input is wrapped in  tags.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $values[1]; ?>"/>
```

gives me in result (that's how it looks like in web inspector in Chrome):

```
<input type="text" value="              <td>2.62</td>">
```

What did I do wrong??

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($values);`?

Comment: You are sure the value of `$values[1]` is not `<td>2.62</td>`?

Comment: I looks like $values[1] has some whitespace and some html in it . . .

Comment: Debug with `echo var_dump($values);` - it certainly looks like there is something else in that variable than you expect

Comment: When I do `print_r($values);` I get `Array ( [0] => 5.32 [1] => 2.62 )`, when I do `echo var_dump($values);` I get `array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "  5.32 " [1]=> string(19) "  2.62 " }`

Comment: View the source when you output the $values[1] in the paragraph tag - I'm going to guess that that has the whitespacee and the table data tag as well, you're just not seeing it rendered in your browser . . . when you put the text in the <input>, you see it since it's just the raw text, no HTML being parsed by the browser . . . Same thing with your print_r and var_dump - you're doing it to a web browser, which interprets the HTML.  Either do it from the console, or view source . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments then replace:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $values[1]; ?>"/>
```

.. with:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo trim(strip_tags($values[1])); ?>"/>
```

It really sounds like a mistake that there can be HTML tags inside your variables and if this should not happen then of course this should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

`$values[1]` contains the data

```
            <td>2.62</td>
```

If your example is from your actual code, take notice that your first variable is `$values[0]` and the input one is `$values[1]`

Comment: Yes, but both of the values: [0] and [1] contains the same format, it doesn't matter which one I put in a text field's value, please, see comment above. I corrected my question contents.